# Как получить версию play-services-auth?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно на сервер отправлять данные при запросе о том какая версия используется в данный момент? Можно ли как то программно получить номер версии?

Comment: `play-services-auth` - это же библиотека, которую вы подключаете? .

Comment: @metalurgus да, но я ж так понимаю, что когда бибилиотека обновляется я должен сбилдить новый файл и поставить его на обновление в маркете, но вдруг не все юзеры обновяться сразу... Или не так?

Comment: Не обязательно это делать. Да и если вы только для этого хотите знать версию, то вы можете вместо версии `play-services-auth` использовать версию своего приложения просто